# Istio locality traffic distribution

Tags: istio

So I have two ingress-gateway pods reside in `us-east-1a` and `us-east-1d`, and I have 5 pods in each az. What I'm trying to do is distribute all the traffic from `us-east-1a` to `us-east 1b` , all the traffic from `us-east-1e` to `us-east-1d`.

Configuration:

```
ip-10-0-111-252.ec2.internal   --> us-east-1a
ip-10-0-120-0.ec2.internal       --> us-east-1b
ip-10-0-130-200.ec2.internal   --> us-east-1e
ip-10-0-149-80.ec2.internal     --> us-east-1d


(base) root@ubuntu:/home/outlier# kubectl get po -o wide -n istio-system 
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE                           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
istio-egressgateway-85c567665-8c49d             1/1     Running   0          23h   10.0.138.81    ip-10-0-130-200.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>
istio-ingressgateway-669cfc876b-b4wg8           1/1     Running   0          23h   10.0.108.90    ip-10-0-111-252.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>
istio-ingressgateway-669cfc876b-bs879           1/1     Running   0          24m   10.0.142.209   ip-10-0-130-200.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>


(base) root@ubuntu:/home/outlier# kubectl get po -o wide
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE                           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
fortio-deploy-6dc9b4d7d9-lxq5w       2/2     Running   0          18h   10.0.137.140   ip-10-0-130-200.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>
recommendation-v2-57ddf9cd95-688tr   2/2     Running   0          44m   10.0.99.243    ip-10-0-111-252.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>
recommendation-v2-57ddf9cd95-968xj   2/2     Running   0          44m   10.0.157.238   ip-10-0-149-80.ec2.internal    <none>           <none>
recommendation-v2-57ddf9cd95-pl2sv   2/2     Running   0          44m   10.0.120.166   ip-10-0-120-0.ec2.internal     <none>           <none>
recommendation-v2-57ddf9cd95-x465z   2/2     Running   0          44m   10.0.135.67    ip-10-0-130-200.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>
```

```
---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: recomm-dr
spec:
  host: recommendation
  trafficPolicy:
    outlierDetection:
      baseEjectionTime: 1m
      consecutiveErrors: 1
      interval: 1s
      maxEjectionPercent: 50
      minHealthPercent: 50
#    connectionPool:
#      http:
#        http1MaxPendingRequests: 1
#        maxRequestsPerConnection: 1
    loadBalancer:
      localityLbSetting:
        enabled: true
        distribute:
        - from: us-east-1/us-east-1a/*
          to:
#            "us-east-1a": 1 
            "us-east-1/us-east-1b/*": 100
#        - from: us-east-1e
#          to:
#            "us-east-1d": 100
  subsets:
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
```

The expected behavior should be I got all the response from recommendation-v2-57ddf9cd95-968xj and recommendation-v2-57ddf9cd95-pl2sv. But the result only contain the other ones

```sh
(base) root@ubuntu:/home/outlier# kubectl exec -it $CLIENT_POD  -c istio-proxy  -- sh -c 'while true; do curl http://httpbin.com/; sleep 1; done'
```

```
recommendation v2 from 'recommendation-v2-57ddf9cd95-x465z': 111
recommendation v2 from 'recommendation-v2-57ddf9cd95-688tr': 97
recommendation v2 from 'recommendation-v2-57ddf9cd95-688tr': 98
recommendation v2 from 'recommendation-v2-57ddf9cd95-x465z': 112
recommendation v2 from 'recommendation-v2-57ddf9cd95-688tr': 99
recommendation v2 from 'recommendation-v2-57ddf9cd95-x465z': 113
```

```
---            

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
      - "*"

---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: recommendation
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - "my-gateway"
  http:
  - name: "other-account-route"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: recommendation
        subset: v2
      weight: 100
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you perform a test and create second `DestinationRule`, let's say `recomm-dr-2` and split those two configs between them? Then the `recomm-dr-1` would have `us-east-1a --> us-east-1b` and the `recomm-dr-2` would have `us-east-1e --> us-east-1d`. This way we can check why the 2nd config is somehow ignored.

Comment: Hi , not sure what's going on but today when I re-run the tast looks like all the distribute settings failed. I've edit the details above and disable one rules as your suggest.

Comment: But this distribution failed after redeploying env or after changing the rules as I suggested?

Comment: Do you use cloud or onprem? If on prem did you label your nodes accordingly?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context what you are doing, where the request comes from (local, external). Any frontend/backend involved? Can you provide an minimal reproducible example? You're sending request towards `httpbin.com` but your destinationroule for host `recommendation`. Can you explain this?

Comment: The environment is AWS eks, httpbin.com is an internal resolved hostname. I'm updating the topic with some more details.

Comment: Please elaborate on this "httpbin.com is an internal resolved hostname" and provide appropriate yaml for this configuration ? what istio and k8s version are you using?